# Call PowerPoint Macro Function from Python

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint

I am wondering how can I have python to call a PowerPoint VBA function? Assume I have the following files in the same folder:

python.py
powerpoint.pptm

In the powerpoint it is all blank except I have 1 module call "module1" and 1 function call "main" which does not take in any arguments. The main function just open a message box and print "Hello World"

This is what I have in Python:

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "\powerpoint.pptm"):
    ppt=win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppt.Presentations.Open(os.getcwd() + "\powerpoint.pptm")

    # The code above worked and open up the powerpoint, but the code below does not work
    ppt.Application.Run("powerpoint.pptm!module1.main")
```

The error code that gives is:

```
638         # no where else to look.
```

--> 639         raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self.*username*, attr))
640
641     def **setattr**(self, attr, value):

AttributeError: PowerPoint.Application.Application

Personally, I doubt I am even on the right path to get this to work. Also the above python code was taken from the code to run an Excel macro and modified. However, it DOES NOT work, would be really glad if anyone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: What means "it doesn't work"? It is hard to help you with such a vague description of the problem.

Comment: Is `main` declared as `Public Sub main` ?

Comment: It seems whether it is public doesn't matter. Luke's solution below works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need ppt.Run not ppt.Application.Run

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "\powerpoint.pptm"):
    ppt=win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppt.Presentations.Open(os.getcwd() + "\powerpoint.pptm")

    ppt.Run("powerpoint.pptm!module1.main")
```

Comment: `ppt` is already an `Application` object, and `ppt.Application` is the same object as `ppt`

Comment: ppt.Application is referring to PowerPoint.Application.Application which is invalid as it's already an application object.


'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    ppt.Application
  File "C:\Users\lukeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 639, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: PowerPoint.Application.Application'

Comment: Sorry Luke you are correct and I was wrong - Python is not VBA and doesn't work the same way.

Comment: This is very helpful and solves the problem. Thanks!